# Ruby Net::OpenTimeout on call to 'puts', weird stacktrace. Multithreaded app

Tags: ruby, multithreading, exception, file-descriptor

I have the below 2 stacktrace's from  my Ruby application.

The first stack trace is showing the exception to be thrown at line 161 of my http.rb file. On line 161 there is a call to **puts()** as you can see in my code snippet below the exception. The stack trace is also showing a call to **write()** that I presume is a low level C call.  The 2nd stack trace is also for a **puts()** but in a different part of the application. This line is actually just temporay debug info. Here you can see we are using a Monitor to synchronise some logging because it's a multithreaded app.

The exception however is a Net::OpenTimeout exception.  I do have code elsewhere that is performing network connections and there is an exception handler elsewhere for catching them.

**How can a call to 'puts' result a Net::Timeout exception?**

Could there be something funny going on with file descriptors?

> **Net::OpenTimeout**, "execution expired", "[\"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/http.rb:161:in
>   '**write**'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/http.rb:161:in
>   '**puts**'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/http.rb:161:in
>   'puts'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/http.rb:161:in
>   'logResult'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/generic.rb:65:in
>   'rescue in call_check'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/generic.rb:63:in
>   'call_check'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/generic.rb:46:in
>   'block in schedule'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:218:in
>   'do_call'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:262:in
>   'trigger_now'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:307:in
>   'block (3 levels) in start_work_thread'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:310:in
>   'block (2 levels) in start_work_thread'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:296:in
>   'loop'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:296:in
>   'block in start_work_thread'\"]",

```
   if !passed && @@previous_double_check.key?(@key) && !@@previous_double_check[@key]
      puts "#{@key} failed after double check"
      _passed=false
   elsif !passed 
     puts "#{@key} first attempt failed, but marking true"      # line 161           
      opts[:failedPendingDoubleCheck] = true
      _passed=true
   end
```

---

> Net::OpenTimeout, "execution expired",
>   "[\"lib/monitoring/monitor.rb:209:in `write'\",
>   \"lib/monitoring/monitor.rb:209:in`puts'\",
>   \"lib/monitoring/monitor.rb:209:in `puts'\",
>   \"lib/monitoring/monitor.rb:209:in`block (2 levels) in do_check'\",
>   \"lib/monitoring/monitor.rb:208:in `synchronize'\",
>   \"lib/monitoring/monitor.rb:208:in`block in do_check'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/generic.rb:93:in
>   `logResult'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/http.rb:170:in`
>   logResult'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/generic.rb:65:in
>   `rescue in call_check'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/generic.rb:63:in`
>   call_check'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/github/lemonitor/lib/monitoring/checks/generic.rb:46:in
>   `block in schedule'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:218:in`
>   do_call'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:262:in
>   `trigger_now'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:307:in`
>   block (3 levels) in start_work_thread'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:310:in
>   `block (2 levels) in start_work_thread'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:296:in`
>   loop'\",
>   \"/Users/tomburnell/.gem/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.5.2/lib/rufus/scheduler/jobs.rb:296:in
>   `block in start_work_thread'\"]", 70196180003060]

```
    logger[:result] = lambda do |type, passed, opts|
      $logger_mutex.synchronize do
        puts "LOGGING RESULT " + Thread.current.object_id.to_s         # line 209
        log_event "METRIC ns=hc.check type=#{type} result=#{passed ? 'ok':'fail'} key=#{key.join('/').to_json} #{opts.map{|k,v|"#{k}=#{safe_to_json(v)}" if k and v}.compact.join(' ')}"
        $last_result = passed;
        puts "POST LOGGING RESULT " + Thread.current.object_id.to_s
      end
    end
```

---

> thread #92, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
>       frame #0: 0x00007fff68cb8a16 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_cvwait + 10
>       frame #1: 0x00007fff68e81589 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_cond_wait + 732
>       frame #2: 0x000000010e3bb179 libruby.2.6.dylib`gvl_acquire_common [inlined] native_cond_timedwait(cond=<unavailable>,
>   mutex=<unavailable>) at thread_pthread.c:529
>       frame #3: 0x000000010e3bb13a libruby.2.6.dylib`gvl_acquire_common [inlined] do_gvl_timer(vm=, th=) at
>   thread_pthread.c:219
>       frame #4: 0x000000010e3bb0eb libruby.2.6.dylib`gvl_acquire_common(vm=0x00007fdcbb801c00,
>   th=0x00007fdcc0e1b8e0) at thread_pthread.c:253
>       frame #5: 0x000000010e3b2ed1 libruby.2.6.dylib`blocking_region_end [inlined] gvl_acquire(vm=0x00007fdcbb801c00, th=) at
>   thread_pthread.c:282
>       frame #6: 0x000000010e3b2eb5 libruby.2.6.dylib`blocking_region_end(th=0x00007fdcc0e1b8e0,
>   region=0x000070000b8f34b0) at thread.c:1415
>       frame #7: 0x000000010e3b2a70 libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_thread_io_blocking_region(func=(libruby.2.6.dylib`internal_writev_func
>   at io.c:1025), data1=0x000070000b8f3688, fd=<unavailable>) at
>   thread.c:1566
>       frame #8: 0x000000010e2a927f libruby.2.6.dylib`io_fwritev [inlined] rb_writev_internal(fd=, iov=,
>   iovcnt=) at io.c:1078
>       frame #9: 0x000000010e2a9264 libruby.2.6.dylib`io_fwritev [inlined] io_binwritev(iov=<unavailable>, iovcnt=<unavailable>,
>   fptr=<unavailable>) at io.c:1614
>       frame #10: 0x000000010e2a8fef libruby.2.6.dylib`io_fwritev(argc=, argv=,
>   fptr=0x00007fdcbb531370) at io.c:1678
>       frame #11: 0x000000010e299de5 libruby.2.6.dylib`io_writev(argc=2, argv=0x000070000b8f38c0, io=<unavailable>) at io.c:1723
>       frame #12: 0x000000010e3f42cc libruby.2.6.dylib`vm_call0_body at vm_eval.c:86
>       frame #13: 0x000000010e3f41f7 libruby.2.6.dylib`vm_call0_body [inlined] vm_call0_cfunc(ec=0x00007fdcc0e4c668,
>   argv=0x000070000b8f38c0) at vm_eval.c:100
>       frame #14: 0x000000010e3f41f7 libruby.2.6.dylib`vm_call0_body(ec=0x00007fdcc0e4c668,
>   calling=, ci=, cc=,
>   argv=0x000070000b8f38c0) at vm_eval.c:131
>       frame #15: 0x000000010e3f2740 libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_funcallv [inlined] rb_vm_call0(ec=<unavailable>, recv=<unavailable>,
>   id=<unavailable>, argc=2, argv=<unavailable>, me
>   =<unavailable>) at vm_eval.c:60
>       frame #16: 0x000000010e3f270d libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_funcallv [inlined] rb_call0(ec=0x00007fdcc0e4c668, recv=140586015886600,
>   mid=8481, argc=2, argv=, scope=CALL_FCALL,
>   self=140586015886600) at vm_eval.c:308
>       frame #17: 0x000000010e3f26f7 libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_funcallv [inlined] rb_call(recv=140586015886600, mid=8481, argc=2,
>   argv=0x0000000000000000, scope=CALL_FCALL) at vm_eval.c:601
>       frame #18: 0x000000010e3f26f7 libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_funcallv(recv=140586015886600, mid=8481, argc=2,
>   argv=) at vm_eval.c:823
>       frame #19: 0x000000010e299813 libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_io_puts(argc=<unavailable>,
>   argv=0x0000000116750320, out=<unavailable>) at io.c:7756
>       frame #20: 0x000000010e3f42cc libruby.2.6.dylib`vm_call0_body at vm_eval.c:86
>       frame #21: 0x000000010e3f41f7 libruby.2.6.dylib`vm_call0_body [inlined] vm_call0_cfunc(ec=0x00007fdcc0e4c668,
>   argv=0x0000000116750320) at vm_eval.c:100
>       frame #22: 0x000000010e3f41f7 libruby.2.6.dylib`vm_call0_body(ec=0x00007fdcc0e4c668,
>   calling=, ci=, cc=,
>   argv=0x0000000116750320) at vm_eval.c:131
>       frame #23: 0x000000010e3f2740 libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_funcallv [inlined] rb_vm_call0(ec=<unavailable>, recv=<unavailable>,
>   id=<unavailable>, argc=1, argv=<unavailable>, me=<unavailable>) at
>   vm_eval.c:60
>       frame #24: 0x000000010e3f270d libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_funcallv [inlined] rb_call0(ec=0x00007fdcc0e4c668, recv=140586015886600,
>   mid=16017, argc=1, argv=, scope=CALL_FCALL,
>   self=140586015886600) at vm_eval.c:308
>       frame #25: 0x000000010e3f26f7 libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_funcallv [inlined] rb_call(recv=140586015886600, mid=16017, argc=1,
>   argv=0x000070000b8f3a80, scope=CALL_FCALL) at vm_eval.c:601
>       frame #26: 0x000000010e3f26f7 libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_funcallv(recv=140586015886600, mid=16017, argc=1,
>   argv=) at vm_eval.c:823
>       frame #27: 0x000000010e403311 libruby.2.6.dylib`vm_call_cfunc [inlined] vm_call_cfunc_with_frame(ec=<unavailable>,
>   reg_cfp=<unavailable>, ci=0x00007fdcbb56b0c0) at vm_insnhelper.c:1908
>       frame #28: 0x000000010e403224 libruby.2.6.dylib`vm_call_cfunc(ec=,
>   reg_cfp=, calling=, ci=0x00007fdcbb56b0c0,
>   cc=) at vm_insnhelper.c:1924
>       frame #29: 0x000000010e3e9adf libruby.2.6.dylib`vm_exec_core(ec=<unavailable>,
>   initial=<unavailable>) at insns.def:763
>       frame #30: 0x000000010e3fdd8e libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_vm_exec(ec=0x00007fdcc0e4c668,
>   mjit_enable_p=) at vm.c:0
>       frame #31: 0x000000010e3f6fce libruby.2.6.dylib`rb_yield [inlined] vm_yield at vm.c:1155

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:python] if it's about Ruby? I couldn't find any mention of Python in this question

Comment: What @ForceBru said. Please retag your question as Ruby. You're not going to get much help with Python.

Comment: Oops thanks for the edit!